# Change z-index on hover

Tags: css, hover, z-index, tumblr

I am trying to change the z-index of the image posts that when you hover over them, it comes in front and cover the big white text.
Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

http://hkumbrella.tumblr.com/

Image post css:

```
#post img {
width:100%;
z-index: -100;
}
#post img:hover {
opacity:1;
z-index: 100000 !important;
```

White text css(2014):

```
.subtitle2{
top:45%;
left:2%;
font-family:arimo;
font-weight:bold;
color: white;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:75px;
letter-spacing:-3px;
text-align:center;
position: fixed;
z-index:100;
color: #FFFFFF !important;
{block:Permalink}display:none;{/block:Permalink}
}
```

Comment: The second css snippet is pretty broken towards the end...

Answer (score 1):

Set `#wrapper`'s `z-index` higher then 100.

All the images are inside `#wrapper` div, and its `z-index` is less then its sibling `.subtiles`, so even if you set higher `z-index` for children of `#wrapper`, it won't come in front.

and you are using `#post` multiple at places in your page. you are not suppose to use `id` multiple places, instead use classes, they are meant for that only.

Comment: I can make the wrapper come in front, but I want to keep the .subtitles on top the way it is, ONLY when you hover over the images, they overlap the .subtitles
Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't think it is purely possible with the css you will have to write some Javascript for that.